# Checking If iframe have finished loading?

Tags: html, iframe, cross-domain, xss, loading

It is possible to monitor If iframe have loaded (Iframe is not in my domain)? I don't own the page. 
Cross-domain will prevent it from detecting?:

Any solutions,

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if the `<iframe>` node has an `onload` event, or maybe you could try using your window's `onload` event (if the frame is not added dynamically by JS)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Sorry. (Actually, that's probably a good thing)

This kind of voodoo only works for `<img onerror="" onload="">`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible, but it doesn't seem that it is.. 
every time I try I get an error message similar to this:

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL *C:\test.html* from frame with URL *http://www.google.ca/*. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Answer (score 0):

If the `<iframe>` is dynamically created, with jQuery, you can try this -

```
$("#iframeId").load(function(){
  //your code here
});
```